# Check if my application has focus / topmost vb.net

Tags: vb.net, focus

I need to check if my application is hidden behind any other windows / lost focus. Basically i have an application and if an event occurs and the application is not focused i can flash the window.

I actually wrote this a few month ago but lost the source, before i used something simple like application.focused,  although for the life of me can't remember what it was. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetActiveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646292%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the hWnd of the active window and then compare it to the hWnd of your window. If you don't already know the hWnd of your window you can use [Control.Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [FindWindowEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindowex) to get it.

If you need to check if your window is set to be top-most, there's sample code at the bottom of [getwindowlong on pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowlong) in C# but you should be able to write the VB equivalent from the content given in the rest of the page.